# CAN bus and SPI communication in Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, can-bus, socketcan

I am developing a prototype for adaptive cruise control using two raspberry pi's. I have tested SPI on pi and it works (checked it through loopback). Now i want to write this data to the cotroller. So, after referring to resources i found Socketcan should be used in order to interface can controller with the pi. So i request some one to explain how the communication happens like 
1. After writing to spi how the can controller can take that data?
2. If socketcan be used to take data from spi , i need to know how?

Thanks

Comment: have you used python on the pi? yet

Comment: Yes i have tested the spi loopback in python ..and also tested a ultrasonic sensor.i need idea how to take data from spi to the CAN controller